# I sent My ETC to my ETH address

Tags: transactions, cpp-ethereum, ethereum-classic

I've sent a mistake ETC from ETH address from poloniex.
How do i do now.
This is my transaction (this is a fresh address)
http://gastracker.io/tx/0x13ae860aa07336c3343cc408bc9360a89c64703c690e64380a34ceaa4bc71e02

PS: let me explain more.
I want withdraw 7.5ETH from Poloniex to MyEtherWallet.com address. But I sent 7.5ETC from Poloniex to an ETC address "0x407e1bb8b5c114e40469eedb5632518b68f9be38". My ETH address has same address like this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific, what would you like to happen? You bought ETC on Poloniex, I understand that much.

Comment: let me explain more. I want withdraw 7.5ETH from Poloniex to MyEtherWallet.com address. But I sent 7.5ETC from Poloniex to an ETC address "0x407e1bb8b5c114e40469eedb5632518b68f9be38". My ETH address has same address like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely use the same keys. You cannot actually send ETH to ETC or vice versa (if I hand you a US dollar, even if you were expecting a Euro, it's still a US dollar). It looks like you sent ether on the ETC chain in Polloniex. To regain access to this ETC, open an ETC wallet program and import the keys created by your ETH wallet.

In theory (or at least for the purposes of this discussion), every Ethereum address has a key that unlocks it. When you "create an Ethereum address", you're really generating a secret (private) key and then figuring out which account it unlocks. Since the same keys work in both the ETH chain and ETC chain, when you generate an Ethereum account key, it unlocks *both* accounts. Since all accounts start off as empty, if you look for your account balance on the wrong chain, you'll see it has no ether.

Thus, you should think of your address (and account) as an Ethereum address (and account). The keys for all Ethereum accounts unlock ether stored in the Ethereum Classic and Ethereum (non-classic) chains. However, the amount of ether each account contains depends on which blockchain you check. When you sent ether on the ETC chain from Poloniex, the Ethereum account with the address 0x407e1bb8b5c114e40469eedb5632518b68f9be38 *on the Ethereum Classic chain* was credited with 7.49 ether. Since it's on the Ethereum Classic chain, we say that you sent 7.49 ETC. No ether was sent on the Ethereum (non-classic) chain, so 0 ETH was sent. If someone sent you an ether on the Ethereum (non-classic) chain, then the key for the 0x407e1bb8b5c114e40469eedb5632518b68f9be38 account would have access to 7.49 ETC *and* 1 ETH. So you need to export the keys you generated in your wallet that sends and receives transactions on the Ethereum (non-classic) chain. Next, you import the same keys into a wallet that is sending and receiving transactions on the Ethereum Classic chain.

For example, you can see that account 0xdf15b90591fcfc3f313291c6c1fdedc2f2b34373 has ether stored in the [Ethereum Classic chain](https://etcchain.com/addr/0xDf15b90591fcfc3F313291C6c1FDedc2f2B34373) and the [Ethereum (non-classic) chain](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdf15b90591fcfc3f313291c6c1fdedc2f2b34373) (and the transactions list and final balances are different, too).

Comment: let me explain more. I want withdraw 7.5ETH from Poloniex to MyEtherWallet.com address. But I sent 7.5ETC from Poloniex to an ETC address "0x407e1bb8b5c114e40469eedb5632518b68f9be38". My ETH address has same address like this. I have both ETC and ETH wallet on poloniex.

Comment: You can think of ETH and ETC as being two parallel universes (like in science fiction movies) where most things are the same -- but slightly different. In fact, ETH and ETC used to be the same universe. Now, you can think of your account keys as the keys to a house in the two separate universes. At some point in the past, the houses contained the same things, but after the hard fork in July 2016 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethereum_Classic), they could contain different things. The same key still gets you into both houses and have the same addresses. Some houses were empty before the fork.

Comment: Thank you very much. After login to myetherwallet account and select the ETC account. I found my etc here.