# Restoring ETC using an ETH wallet

Tags: ethereum-classic

I mined some Ethereum before the DAO hardfork. At the time I didn't really understand what the hardfork meant. I just went with the flow and updated the software and I didn't realize I also received coins on the Ethereum Classic network. Now that I do, I would like to access them. But I don't know where to start.

While mining, the ETC was sent to a contract, not an account. And in my ETH wallet, I can't see the contract. I remember deleting or cancelling the contract after I transferred all the received mined coins. But this was on the ETH network, not the ETC network. I looked up the ETC contract address on gastracker.io and it still has the ETC balance I expected. The contract  belongs to the wallet I still have the keystore file for. I just don't know how to access this contract to transfer the coins on the ETC network.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could point me in the right direction. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out... I tried so many things, but the Mist software for Ethereum Classic is full with bugs in the features that I needed. In the end I started to read up on contracts and my eye fell upon the option to suicide a contract (kill it). So I went into

MyEtherWallet.com -> Contracts

Put in all the information requested and chose the Kill contract method. This killed the contract and the funds went back to my main address. I then proceeded to move these ETC into my Ledger wallet. This little project took me about 11 hours in total, but I ended up with 209 ETC in my wallet. So this story has a happy ending!

Answer (score 0):

Addresses from ETH are valid in ETC (and also the other way) [Sent transaction between ETH and ETC accounts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23759/sent-transaction-between-eth-and-etc-accounts).

You need to import your ETH keys in a ETC wallet. You can consult in https://ethereumclassic.github.io/ for available wallets.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Ismael. I'm in the process of downloading the blockchain now. Might take a while, even with the --fast and higher cache value in geth.

Comment: I now have all the entire blockchain downloaded and I imported my wallet keys. But the balance shows up as 0. I believe this is because there is no balance on this address, the balance is in a contract. Is there any way I can access the funds within this contract with only the keys to my address?

I have the private key for the address that created the contract.

Comment: I'm afraid it is the same in both ETH and ETC you need to pay for the gas expense to use a contract.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. I don't mind paying gas to get to my coins.  Do you mean I have to have some ETC in my wallet before I can get to the contract?
I have downloaded the entire ETC blockchain with geth and I'm now trying to import the contract into my wallet using Mist. But it has been showing 'Importing' for at least 15 minutes already. So it might have gotten stuck. I'll just keep it running overnight and see what happens.

Comment: After two hours, the Ethereum Wallet Client (Mist 0.9.1) was still showing 'Importing' under the contracts. I have no idea if something got stuck or if this is supposed to take a long time. I do not see heavy load on the machine, so I don't think anything was happening...

To make sure it is not a problem with the balance, I deposited some ETC on the main account address and did the import contract procedure again. But for the last hour it shows 'Importing' as it did before. No indication of anything happening.

Comment: You are better asking a new question for the issue with importing the contract  in ETC, I'm not a ETC user myself so I can't help you with that.